# SharePoint 2010 Windows 7 Ultimate or Professional - VHD

Tags: sharepoint, windows-7, vhd

I’d like to use the VHD from MS in Win 7

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

Which Win 7 do I need Home, Prof., Ultimate, is there a differrence or does it not matter?

Sorry for this stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate can be booted from the VHD, all
>   other editions are not licensed to use the feature and fail to run.
>
> You can use this 3rd party tool:
>
> http://www.vmlite.com/index.php/products/vboot/download
>
> Which allows booting of all Vista/7 Editions as well as XP and Linux.

Thanks to Andre.Ziegler from the Microsoft Technet forums for that one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand you properly I can only boot the SP2010 VHD image if I have Enterprise or Ultimate Ed. and if I use this tool it doesn’t matter. 
Can I only boot the image or is it also possible to start it while running Win 7 “normally” like in Virtual PC

Comment: to run the image concurrently with win7 you will need some sort of virtual machine software.